# JS object inheritance with attributes

Tags: javascript, string, object

Im trying to get a very simple inheritance pattern for my Project going, extending from a base class into a specialized class. However, my specialized class's attributes are being overwritten by the parent's attributes.

Why is that and how can i fix it ?

thanks,

```
function Ship(className, x, y){
    this.className = className;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speed = 0;
}

function Corvette(className, x, y){
    this.className = className;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.speed = 100;        
    Ship.call(this, className, x, y)
}


Corvette.prototype = Object.create(Ship.prototype);   

var ship = new Ship("Biggie", 50, 50);
var corvette = new Corvette("Smallish", 50, 50);

console.log(Corvette.className) // "Smallish" - correct via parameter.
console.log(Corvette.speed) // should be 100, is 0 - not correct, "static" from parent attribute
console.log(Corvette.constructor.name) // Ship
```

Comment: Save yourself the headache of the old "class" system and use [ES6 classes.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: property lookup normally happens from first level object to prototypes.. `Ship.call(this, className, x, y)` This call will replace the speed's value with `0`

Answer (score 1):

Why you have the same properties in the `child` object which are already in the `parent's`?

I suggest you to do

```js
function Ship(className, x, y, speed = 0) {
    this.className = className;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speed = speed;
}

function Corvette(className, x, y, speed = 100) { 
    Ship.call(this, className, x, y, speed);
}

Corvette.prototype = Object.create(Ship.prototype);   
Corvette.prototype.constructor = Corvette;

var ship = new Ship("Biggie", 50, 50);
var corvette = new Corvette("Smallish", 50, 50);

console.log(corvette.className) // "Smallish" - correct via parameter.
console.log(corvette.speed) // should be 100, is 0 - not correct, "static" from parent attribute
console.log(corvette.constructor.name) // Ship
```

and if your browser supports some features of `ES6` use this feature **[ES6 classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)**.

```js
class Ship { // And also Ship is an abstractionm so you can use `abstract` keyword with it
  constructor(className, x, y, speed = 0) {
    this.className = className;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speed = speed;
  }
}

class Corvette extends Ship {
   constructor(className, x, y, speed = 100) {
        super(className, x, y, speed);
   }
}

var ship = new Ship("Biggie", 50, 50);
var corvette = new Corvette("Smallish", 50, 50);

console.log(corvette.className) // "Smallish" - correct via parameter.
console.log(corvette.speed) // should be 100, is 0 - not correct, "static" from parent attribute
console.log(corvette.constructor.name) // Ship
```

Comment: In this way `Corvette.speed` is 0, not 100 as op asked ;)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to move `Ship.call(this, className, x, y)` at the start of Corvette function.

Also, next time, before posting code, check it is correct, you wrote `console.log(Corvette)` instead of `console.log(corvette)`

Another thing: you do not need to repeat params you do not want to overwrite

```js
function Ship(className, x, y){
    this.className = className;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speed = 0;
}

function Corvette(className, x, y){
    Ship.call(this, className, x, y)   
    this.speed = 100;        
}


Corvette.prototype = Object.create(Ship.prototype);   

var ship = new Ship("Biggie", 50, 50);
var corvette = new Corvette("Smallish", 50, 50);

console.log(corvette.className)
console.log(corvette.speed)
console.log(corvette.constructor.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should invoke the parentclass contructor first and then override the properties, this way the properties set by Corvette will not be changed by the parent class  i.e.:

```
function Corvette(className, x, y){
    Ship.call(this, className, x, y)      
    this.speed = 100;        

}
```